# python unittest command lines with inheritance resultclass

Tags: python, unit-testing, command, lines

*I want to my test case in single methods with a customized result.
Inside `test.py` file, the code is like this:

```
class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_isupper1(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())

    def test_isupper2(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
if __name__ == '__main__':        
    runner=unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2,resultclass=myResultclass)
    unittest.main(testRunner=runner)
```

However, if I run in command mode like

```
python -m unittest  test.TestStringMethods.test_isupper1
```

My test result does not include with `myResultclass` (inherits from `unittest.TextTestResult`). unittest uses default resultclass. how can I parameter `myResultclass` from command lines.

I somehow understand if it run in command line, it will not run IF, because it run in `python -m`, if I remove `if __name__ == '__main__'`, python will give me error.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It should work. `I can not run` is too broad. the inheritance is what exactly?

Comment: I try to make it more clearly. please check the code above.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319515/accessing-test-status-in-pyunit-teardown) might be similar to your situation.

Comment: I am using the same solution as (stackoverflow.com/questions/17319515/…) the problem is if I want to run only a single test like 'python -m unittest  test.TestStringMethods.test_isupper1' myResultclass is not called

Comment: `python -m whatever` will skip the `main()`, so this will skip your `myResultClass`. `python test.py` will use your `main()`, use your `myResultClass`, but you cannot control which test to run unless using `addTest` in `main()`. You might get rid of the `main` all together, use `nosetests` instead, you might use nose to customize test results.

Comment: thx, it is working now